# Special Operation on each element of array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to write out data in a very specific format including numbers, dates, strings. My input is an array containing this data but not necessarily in the right format. So I need to apply custom operations on almost every element. The input and output have variable length.

edit: A little bit more clarification here:
I am parsing data from different sources with different formats. The task is to write them out to the same format. I am writing a default parser for each source. There is no way around that. I am writing the data into a format that contains all necessary fields for the output. e.g. [name, data, value, cur1, cur2, ...]
Now I need to format this data in a very specific way . E.g. Add something to the name. Basically I need to modify every element in my array in a rather unique way based on the index.

The input could look something like that:

```
arr = ['name', 30.09.2019, 20.5, 'EUR', 'USD', ....]
# or
arr = ['name', 30.09.2019]
# or
arr = ['name', '', '', '', '', 'note', '17.5', '',....]
```

And then I need to apply some functions to each element.
The only solution I could come up with would be:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
   if(i == 0):
      process_zero(arr[i])
   elif(i == 1):
      process_one(arr[i])
   ...
```

If it wasn't variable length I could do something like this:

```
process_zero(arr[0])
process_one(arr[1])
...
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: `i == 0` - this is just checking  index/position of an element. How about checking values?

Comment: What is the basis for deciding which function to apply? Is it always the index where item appears? Is the item's type? Something else?

Comment: For one thing writing `for i in range(0, arr):` will crash with TypeError --> you need `range(0, len(arr))`. You are not accessing the items in the list this way but you are creating an index `i`. It would be best and idiomatic python to write `for item in arr:` where item in this example would be the actual value inside the list. If you need an index also then write `for indx, item in enumerate(arr):`.

Comment: It is purely based on the index. Yeah you are right about `len(arr)` I missed that when I tried to write this example. Definitely better with enumerate. Thanks.

Comment: @Julian: Is there some underlying structure here? That is, are every five indices a "block" of data, so 0-4 are associated with each other, then 5-9, then 10-14, etc.? If so, you shouldn't have a flat `list`, you should have a `list` of five-`tuple`s (so you can iterate over blocks and process each block separately, unpacking the five elements of the block to useful names, and calling the appropriate processing function on each name without an inner loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the decision of which behavior you want is based entirely on the index of the element, you could make a list of functions that correspond to the elements in the array. How complicated this is depends on the variety of behavior and how important validation of each data type is. Looking at your latest example, it seems like you will need to at least check for empty strings.

Then you can simply `zip()` the list with the functions and call them. Your function list will need to have as many functions as element in the longest data you hope to process. If you zip with a sorter set of data it will work fine -- a longer set will ignore the extra data.

For example:

```
# Some function to handle particular types of data
def processNum(n):
    if n is None:
        print("no value")
        return
    try:
        n = float(n)
        n *= 3
        return f'Handle number: {n}'
    except ValueError:
        return "Bad input"

def currency(c):
    if isinstance(c, str) and c != '':
        return f'currency in: {c}'

# list of functions to apply (expecting at most 5 items to process)
processors = [
    lambda x: "Processed - 1: " + x,
    lambda x: "Processed - 2:" + x,
    processNum,
    currency,
    currency
]
```

Then you can call them in a loop:

```
arr = ['name', '30.09.2019', 30.5, 'EUR', 'USD']
for f,a in zip(processors, arr):
    print(f(a))
```

or, if you want a new list, in a comprehension:

```
[f(a) for f,a in zip(processors, arr)]
```

**Result**

```
['Processed - 1: name',
 'Processed - 2:30.09.2019',
 'Handle number: 91.5',
 'currency in: EUR',
 'currency in: USD']
```

Obviously the details will depend on how you need to process each item.

Comment: That is great idea! I will use that. That will also handle the problem of variable length since is will stop at the last element in `arr`. Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 2):

Since the array is variable length, it sounds like it's not really an appropriate structure in which to put your data. Make a dictionary or a class (or for Python >=3.7, a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)) that contains your data in a more structured format.

```
# With dictionaries
sample = {'name' : 'Jane', 'USD' : 3.50, ... }

def myfunc(data_dict):
    data_dict['name'] = data_dict['name'].upper()
    data_dict['USD'] += 1
    ...

myfunc(sample)

# With classes
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name = '', USD = 0, ...):
        self.name = name
        self.USD = USD
        ...

    def myfunc(self):
        self.name = self.name.upper()
        self.USD += 1
        ...

sample = MyClass('Jane', 3.5, ...)
sample.myfunc()
```

Comment: Great point! What data type is preferable? But I still need to run through all my data and see if it is present. What is I only have the `name` field but not the `USD`?

Comment: Minor note: `data_dict['name'].upper()`/`self.name.upper()` without assigning the result is a wasteful noop. If the goal would be to convert the input to upper case, you'd need to assign back to the key/attribute, e.g. `data_dict['name'] = data_dict['name'].upper()` or `self.name = self.name.upper()`.

Comment: @Julian: How do you tell? Your question gives nothing for us to go on, as far as determining where records split, how you know which index corresponds to which logical field, etc.

Comment: So Basically I am parsing csv files from different sources which all have their own formatting. So I am trying to put them all into the same structure and then write them back out to a csv from this structure.